# KVM-Host OS recommendation

Tags: linux, virtualization, unix, kvm-virtualization

I am about to migrate a server installation (one OS) to a newer hardware and wish to enable/use KVM. So the hardware is fixed (https://www.hetzner.de/hosting/produkte_rootserver/ex40) , now I got the dilemma of choosing an OS.

Functionalities I am expecting to be met:

- Apache 2 (2.2.12 or later) or any HTTP-Server with SNI Extension

  - PHP 5
  - MySQL 5
- KVM virtualisation
- SSH deamon
- Nagios capability for monitoring every vServer
- Security updates for at least 5 years
- Low overhead (usage of system ressources)
- No licensing fee

The focus of the selected OS is, besides those basic features, to be stable (OS as well as repo packages) and long time supported (5yrs or longer).

Comment: You only really have two choices here. Evaluate them both.

Comment: SuSE!?! Right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any enterprise Linux distribution will work for you. You're not setting a high bar or standard. [Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/)/[CentOS](https://www.centos.org)... [Debian](http://www.debian.org)... Even [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) can do this.

Otherwise, reference: [How should an IT department choose a standard Linux distribution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/461271/how-should-an-it-department-choose-a-linux-distribution-technical-reasons)

Comment: Are you sure Debian would be up for the task. AFAIK its lifecycle for a supported version is 3yrs as actual version + 1yr as former version.